# Internal storage still being used despite of sd card

Tags: insufficient-memory

I have a 4 GB micro sd card mounted in my Micromax Bolt A58. But, whenever I install some apps, it shows "not enough storage space". I went to the settings and set the default download location to micro sd card but in vain. It still shows the same result. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the app management option to move programs to external storage.  While apps can be installed on the sdcard, they still need space on the internal storage for actually running.